# Why is my javascript not looping

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which works fine for the first row, but doesn't seem to loop through the table

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" id="demotbl">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">AA1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="prodref">BB1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">CC1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">DD1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">EE1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodre5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">FF1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var x = document.getElementById("demotbl").rows.length;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " tr elements in the table.";    
        var prodref = document.getElementById("prodref").innerHTML;
        var i = 0;
        do {
        document.getElementById("h_prodref").value = prodref;
        i++;
        }
        while (i < x);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My understanding (which is very basic) is that the code will look for a `id` called `prodref` and then copy the cell value to the text box, and work its way down until it has completed all rows.

Comment: `id` must be unique to a page - i.e. you have many `id="prodref"` and `id="h_prodref"` - this will not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mention above `id` must be unique. I create the following example using classes instead:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demotbl").rows.length;;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " tr elements in the table.";
var prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("prodref");
var h_prodref = document.getElementsByClassName("h_prodref");
var i = 0;
for (i; i < prodref.length; i++) {
  h_prodref[i].value = prodref[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" id="demotbl">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">AA1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" class="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">BB1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" class="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">CC1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" class="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">DD1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" class="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">EE1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" class="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="prodref">FF1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" class="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Example with your original html that I **don't** suggest using [**Document.querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demotbl").rows.length;;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " tr elements in the table.";
var prodref = document.querySelectorAll("#prodref");
var h_prodref = document.querySelectorAll("#h_prodref");
var i = 0;
for (i; i < prodref.length; i++) {
  h_prodref[i].value = prodref[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" id="demotbl">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">AA1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">BB1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">CC1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">DD1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">EE1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prodref">FF1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also you have a typo here:

```
<tr>
    <td id="prodref">EE1</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodre5"></td>
  </tr>
```

`id` is `h_prodref` no `h_prodre5`.

Comment: Will this method work on a table with a repeating region?

Comment: @JonathanGriffin What do you mean _repeating region_? Assuming you mean more `tr`'s? Then yes.

Comment: I am using dreamweaver to build the webpage and they have an option to repeat a region (in this case a table row), to the number of occurrences in the recordset.

Comment: @JonathanGriffin If you use the same name convention for `input`'s and `td`' you won't have any problem.

Comment: @JonathanGriffin Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" id="demotbl">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td id="prodref1">AA1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="prodref2">BB1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="prodref3">CC1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="prodref4">DD1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="prodref5">EE1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="prodref6">FF1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="h_prodref" id="h_prodref6"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = document.getElementById("demotbl").rows.length - 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " tr elements in the table.";
        var i = 0;
        do {
            var prodref = document.getElementById("prodref" + (i + 1)).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("h_prodref" + (i + 1)).value = prodref;
            i++;
        }
        while (i < x);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that this will be the solution to your problem. I have done something similar in the past. My tip is not to use 'id' when dealing with more than one element but to use 'class' instead. Hope you fix it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have many elements with the same id. id is always unique to a element. If you are using id's as a way to say apply the same styles to multiple elements you should use a class instead.

In your code the statement:

```
document.getElementById("prodref")
```

will always return you the first element matching the id: "prodref". Which is the element:

```
<td id="prodref">AA1</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

.getElementById() returns the same element so you are setting the same td in every loop. This will do what you wanted;

```
var i = 0; 
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
do {
    elements[i+1].firstChild.value = elements[i].innerText;
    i = i+2;
    }
while (i < elements.length);
```